# How to control the properties of multiple objects?

Tags: java, oop, properties, constructor, reference

I'm using OOP for a class assignment and I'm still learning basics and I came to ask how you could reference the properties of an object while there are multiple objects.

```
public class Shirts
{
  private static int shirtSize;
  private static boolean sleeves;
  private static String color;
  private static String pattern;
  private static double price;

  public Shirts(int size, boolean sleeve, String hue, String design, double cost){
    shirtSize = size;
    sleeves = sleeve;
    color = hue;
    pattern = design;
    price = cost;
  }
```

My issue would be that if I create a second object, I can no longer reference the properties of the first object because once the second object is created, all of the variables in the Shirts class are assigned **new** values.

```
Shirts testA = new Shirts(10,true,"green","stripes",35.00);
Shirts testB = new Shirts(11,false,"orange","plain",33.00);
```

Is there a quick way around this?

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `static` keyword from your fields in `Shirts` class.

Comment: That helped, however, I receive an error message stating I can't make a static reference to a non-static variable. 'return shirtSize;' is showing an error along with the rest of my return statements.

Comment: @MichaelFreaney from your posted code, there's no way to obtain that problem. Please update the post with the relevant code where this error arises and I'll update my answer to explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Static is a class member. So static will work on the class level. By removing static you will solve your problem.

[Good reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) about 'static' by oracle

Answer (score 0):

If you define your variables as *static*, then all *instances* of that class share the same values.. Hence all your instances share the static fields. Remove the *static* keyword and make them *instance level fields* so that they will be unique for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please, remember that `static` modifier means that the property belongs to the class, not to the instance! Therefore, all the instances (what you get when you invoke the constructor) will share the same values for the static properties.

I hope this answer helps to understand what is wrong not only make it work this time.